# IIs there any way to put a name to a column used in both GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to find the closest date to 31 March for every year.

```
SELECT MAX(date_close)
FROM stock s
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.date_close) = '03'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.date_close)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.date_close);
```

Because `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.date_close)` apppears 2 times, I would like to ask if we can give it a name and thus compactify the query.

Comment: It would be nice, but no. (At least in Oracle; there may be other dialects that allow it.) This is unfortunate; there is no logical reason the language couldn't allow the creation of aliases in the `group by` clause. Oracle SQL only allows it in `select`. In your example, the expression is simple enough; if it was much more complex, you would give it a name in a subquery, and then group and order by it (by a short alias) in an outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lateral` to introduce a reusable expression

```
SELECT MAX(date_close)
FROM stock s
  , lateral (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.date_close) y FROM DUAL) t
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.date_close) = '03'
GROUP BY t.y
ORDER BY t.y
```